# Recursion to find last index of common digit between two ints

Tags: java, recursion, integer

I'm trying to implement a method that finds the highest index of common digit between two ints like so:
  a = 2**2**24 , b = 4**2**22 the result would be index = 2, which means the index is in reverse. I managed to find the first common digit, but I'm having trouble finding the last common digit. This the method to find the first common digit:

```
private static int getLowestIndexWithSameDigit(int a, int b) {
    if (a < 0 || b < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Ambos os argumentos devem ser positivos: " + a + " " + b);

    else {
        if (a % 10 == b % 10) {
            return indice;
        } else if (a / 10 != 0 && b / 10 != 0) {
            indice++;
            return getLowestIndexWithSameDigit(a / 10, b / 10);
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

And the method to initialize index as 0 everytime getLowestIndexWithSameDigit is used:

```
private static void test_getLowestIndexWithSameDigit(int a, int b) {
    try {

        System.out.print("getLowestIndexWithSameDigit (" + a + ", " + b + ") = ");
        indice = 0;
        int res = getLowestIndexWithSameDigit(a, b);
        System.out.println(res);

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I was trying to adapt this method in some way, but I don't think it's adaptable to find the last common digit. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `indice`? You forgot to show the declaration.

Comment: It's the index of the first common digit I return, it's initialized as 0.

Comment: I mean where is it declared? Your method does not compile.

Comment: I have another method called test_getLowestIndexWithSameDigit that declares it with value 0, so everytime this method is called, index starts with zero again.

Comment: Then show that method as well. Make a [mcve]

Comment: Indexing is not clear. Does 2 mean 2nd digit from left using 1 base index ?  Or 3ed digit from left using 0 base index ? If you use the 2nd option, than I guess you assume both numbers are of the same length.

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler to convert the `int`s to `String`s:

```
//you can overload method to support other primitives 
private static int getHighestIndexWithSameDigit(int a, int b) {
    String aS = String.valueOf(a);
    String bS = String.valueOf(b);
    return getHighestIndexWithSameDigit(aS, bS);
}
//helper method to set strat index 
private static int getHighestIndexWithSameDigit(String aS, String bS) {
    return getHighestIndexWithSameDigit(aS, bS, 1);
}
//recursively check first letter. First index is 1 - indicates first char from left  
private static int getHighestIndexWithSameDigit(String aS, String bS, int index) {
    int aLength = aS.length(), bLength = bS.length();
    if((aLength == 0) || (bLength == 0)) { return -1;}
    if(aS.charAt(0) == bS.charAt(0)) { return index; }
    //remove first letters, update index 
    return getHighestIndexWithSameDigit(aS.substring(1, aLength),
                                bS.substring(1, bLength), ++index);
}
```

Test by `System.out.println(getHighestIndexWithSameDigit(2224 , 4222) );`

**Edit:** 
The code posted assumed that the first index is 1 (1 base), where index of value 1 indicates the first digit from left. 
If you meant to use 0 base index, counting from right two of the method should change slightly :

```
//helper method to set start index.
private static int getHighestIndexWithSameDigit(String aS, String bS) {
    return getHighestIndexWithSameDigit(aS, bS, aS.length()-1);
}
//recursively check first letter. Index 0 - indicates last char
private static int getHighestIndexWithSameDigit(String aS, String bS, int index) {
    System.out.println(aS +"  "+ bS);
    int aLength = aS.length(), bLength = bS.length();
    if((aLength == 0) || (bLength == 0)) { return -1;}
    if(aS.charAt(0) == bS.charAt(0)) { return index; }
    return getHighestIndexWithSameDigit(aS.substring(1, aLength),
                                bS.substring(1, bLength), --index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the lowest or the highest should only be a matter of when you stop the loop, no?
The slightly rewritten version of your code below did the trick for me at least.

```
private static int getDatIndex(int a, int b, boolean getDatLow) {
    int indice = -1;
    int index = 0;

    while (a/10 != 0 && b/10 != 0) {
        if (a % 10 == b % 10) {
            indice = index;
            // If you want the lowest common digit index: stop the loop.
            if (getDatLow) {
                break;
            }
        }

        a = a/10;
        b = b/10;
        index++;
    }

    return indice;
}
```